# Wicket error in loading HomePage

Tags: java, wicket, runtimeexception

I wrote a wicket application using wicket archetype in wicket.apache.org
But when I added my code, it didn't accept my pages and throw a run time exception:

> Last cause: Class org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory can not access a member of class ece.se.noodle.ui.login.LoginPage with modifiers ""
>
> WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'ece.se.noodle.ui.login.LoginPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!

I extends my pages from wicket WebPage and use `RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException` for redirecting to LoginPage. But neither DashbordPage nor LoginPage can be loaded.

Can someone please tell me where did I did wrong? Or what should I do to fix it?

Comment: Show us your constructor

Comment: There was an Exception throen in your constructor. It would be very helpfull to get a look at both, the constructor and the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed page/request lifecycle. If you require user to log in use AuthenticatedWebApplication instead and annotation based strategy.

If you throws RestartResponseAtInterceptPageException directly you could implement a wrong condition when to throw that exception. E.g. if you is not signed in, throw the exception, if the user is already signed (it is usually a flag in session), do not throw the exception.

See authentication examples on http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/index.html